# Sudoku solution validator on Codewars

Tags: javascript

This code in JavaScript works, but can somebody explain to me what `board[3][8] != board[8][3]` does or to be more precise how does this piece of code checks if rows and columns numbers are not repeated. Thank you!

```js
function validSolution(board) {
    let count0 = 0;
    let count1 = 0;
    let count2 = 0;
    let count3 = 0;
    let count4 = 0;
    let count5 = 0;
    let count6 = 0;
    let count7 = 0;
    let count8 = 0;
    let count9 = 0;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        count0 += board[i][0];
        count1 += board[i][1];
        count2 += board[i][2];
        count3 += board[i][3];
        count4 += board[i][4];
        count5 += board[i][5];
        count6 += board[i][6];
        count7 += board[i][7];
        count8 += board[i][8];
    }

    return (count0 === 45 && count1 === 45 && count2 === 45 && count3 === 45 
        && count4 === 45 && count5 === 45 && count6 === 45 && count7 === 45 &&
        count8 === 45 && board[3][8] != board[8][3] );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That additional check does make sure there's at least **some** variation in the numbers on the board, but it does **not** make sure the solution is actually valid.

Take this board for example:

```js
let board = [
 [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
 [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
 [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
 [4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6],
 [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
 [6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4],
 [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
 [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
 [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]
];
```

All of these rows have totals of 45, *and* grid positions `[3][8]` and `[8][3]` are not equal. `validSolution` incorrectly considers this board to be a valid solution...

I came up with another validation method:

```js
function validSolution(board) {
  var boardx = board.map(x => new Set(x).size == 9 ? x.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0) : 0);
  var boardy = board[0].map((x,col,b) => board.map(x => x[col])).map(x => new Set(x).size == 9 ? x.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0) : 0);
  return new Set(boardx).size == 1 && boardx[0] == 45 && new Set(boardy).size == 1 && boardy[0] == 45;
}
```

---

*A little explanation*:

`boardx` will calculate the sum of each **row** (`x.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0)`) if it consists of 9 unique values (`new Set(x).size == 9` <sup>1</sup>)

`boardy` will calculate the sum of each **column**, but first it has to 'rotate' the grid (`board[0].map((x,col,b) => board.map(x => x[col]))`, followed by the same method we did earlier.

For a valid board, `boardx` and `boardy` should both consist of 9 elements of value `45`. So, we check if both `boardx` and `boardy` only have 1 unique value, and that value is `45`

---

<sup>1</sup> The [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object can only store unique values, therefore it's a perfect tool to quickly check the number of unique elements in an array.

Comment: I'm new at coding so your answer and explanation helped me and saved me some time on checking what this methods or object do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that [3][8] != [8][3] is necessary? In sudoku those two cells don't matter to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's exactly what I'm trying to understand. Without this, code is not working, and with this is working perfectly without any sense. I know how to play sudoku so i thought maybe this have some programing meaning.

P.S It also works with  [0][1] != [1][0],  [5][6] != [6][5],  [1][8] != [8][1] etc..